# Print to PDF not working

Tags: vba, excel

My code is suppose to check cell j2 for an email address and if found, convert that specific tab to pdf and save it in a file path that the user chooses. It works fine on the original workbook I made the macro in. When I copy the code and try running it, it prints to pdf different sheets that don't even have anything in j2 with the incorrect tab name. I keep getting an Run time error 5 Invalid procedure call or argument when i run the code on the print pdf line.

```
Sub SaveSheetsAsPDF()

Dim DestFolder As String
Dim PDFFile As String
Dim wb As Worksheet
Dim AlwaysOverwritePDF As Boolean

'Speed up macro
    Application.ScreenUpdating = False
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual


'Prompt for file destination
With Application.FileDialog(msoFileDialogFolderPicker)

    If .Show = True Then

        DestFolder = .SelectedItems(1)

    Else

        MsgBox "You must specify a folder to save the PDF into." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Must Specify Destination Folder"

        Exit Sub

    End If

End With

'Create new PDF file name including path and file extension

For Each wb In ThisWorkbook.Worksheets


'Test j2 for a mail address
If wb.Range("J2").Value Like "?*@?*.?*" Then

PDFFile = DestFolder & Application.PathSeparator & wb.Name & "-" & Format(Date, "mmyy") & ".pdf"

'If the PDF already exists
If Len(Dir(PDFFile)) > 0 Then

    If AlwaysOverwritePDF = False Then

        OverwritePDF = MsgBox(PDFFile & " already exists." & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Do you want to overwrite it?", vbYesNo + vbQuestion, "File Exists")

        On Error Resume Next
        'If you want to overwrite the file then delete the current one
        If OverwritePDF = vbYes Then

            Kill PDFFile

        Else

            MsgBox "OK then, if you don't overwrite the existing PDF, I can't continue." _
            & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Exiting Macro"

            Exit Sub

        End If

    Else

        On Error Resume Next
        Kill PDFFile

    End If

    If Err.Number <> 0 Then

        MsgBox "Unable to delete existing file.  Please make sure the file is not open or write protected." _
            & vbCrLf & vbCrLf & "Press OK to exit this macro.", vbCritical, "Unable to Delete File"

        Exit Sub

    End If

    End If

End If

'Prints PDF
wb.ExportAsFixedFormat Type:=xlTypePDF, FileName:=PDFFile, Quality:=xlQualityStandard, IncludeDocProperties:=True, IgnorePrintAreas:=False, OpenAfterPublish:=False

Next wb

    MsgBox "All Files Have Been Converted!"

ResetSettings:
    'Resets optimization settings
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationAutomatic
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True

End Sub
```

Edit: Also not all worksheets on the workbook will need to converted. So only the sheets that need to be converted will have the email address in J2.

Comment: `wb.ExportAsFixedFormat` is outside of the `If` block which checks for an email address, so it will run for every sheet

Comment: Ok should it be moved up before the last end if stmt?

Comment: It should be before the `End If` which matches the `If` which checks for the email

Comment: It's fixed! thank you, I've been staring at it so long i didnt event know it as outside the if stmt.

Comment: When you have multiple nested IF statements you should indent your code properly, it makes it much easier to read and troubleshoot.